# len() function calls returning wrong results

Tags: python

How do I make my first if statement true when a device object is equal to 1?

For example, "Lebron" key has one value and it is is "pc" therefore it should print "Lebron's favourite item is pc". But this is not working. instead, my elif statement returns as true instead for all the items in the persons dictionary. I believe my all `len()` function calls result in more than one.

```
persons = {"Rondo": ["computer, pc, phone, ps5, ps4"], 
    "Lebron": ["pc"], 
    "Kobe": ["cellphone"], 
    "Ronel": ["Laptop, Phone"]
    }

for person, devices in persons.items():
    for device in devices:
        if len(device) == 1:
            print(f"{person}'s favorite item is: {device}")
        elif len(device) > 1:
            print(f"{person}'s favorite items are:")
            for device in devices:
                print(device)
```

Comment: `for device in devices` iterates over the strings in each list of devices. `len(device)` would be checking `len("pc")`, which gives you 2.

Comment: "device" is a string and its "len" is the number of characters. The for-loop should be only in the else-block, the if-block doesn't need a loop because there is only one device.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second for loop as you can check the length of devices directly.

Also, your device array is always an array of size 1, so you have to split the items based on whitespace to get a list of individual items.

```
for person, devices in persons.items():
    devices = devices[0].split(", ")
    if len(devices) == 1:
        print(f"{person}'s favorite item is: {devices[0]}")
    elif len(devices) > 1:
        print(f"{person}'s favorite items are: {devices}")
```

Comment: This didn't give me the right result. I believe if you use len(devices) then all of them would return as 1. Because each value attributed to a key is a list.

Comment: Apologies, I see what you have done now. I've fixed the script to work

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the lists already. Remove the second loop:

```
for person, devices in persons.items():
    devices = devices[0].split(', ')
    if len(devices) == 1:
        print(f"{person}'s favorite item is: {device[0]}")
    elif len(devices) > 1:
        print(f"{person}'s favorite items are:")
        for device in devices:
            print(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your device lists are length-1 lists with a `", "` separated string. You could do something like

```py
for person, devices in persons.items():
    device_list = devices[0].split(", ")
    if len(device_list) == 1:
        print(f"{person}'s favorite item is: {device_list[0]}")
    elif len(device_list) > 1:
        print(f"{person}'s favorite items are:")
        for device in device_list:
            print(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

If really the input is made of single string in lists, use string methods:

```
for person, devices in persons.items():
    several = ',' in devices[0]
    verb = 'are:\n' if several else 'is:'
    devs = devices[0].replace(', ', '\n')
    print(f"{person}'s favorite item {verb} {devs}")
```

Output:

```
Rondo's favorite item are:
computer
pc
phone
ps5
ps4
Lebron's favorite item is: pc
Kobe's favorite item is: cellphone
Ronel's favorite item are:
Laptop
Phone
```

If you have a list:

```
persons = {"Rondo": ["computer", "pc", "phone", "ps5", "ps4"], 
    "Lebron": ["pc"], 
    "Kobe": ["cellphone"], 
    "Ronel": ["Laptop", "Phone"]
    }

for person, devices in persons.items():
    verb = 'are:\n' if len(devices) > 1 else 'is: '
    devs = '\n'.join(devices)
    print(f"{person}'s favorite item {verb}{devs}")
```

Comment: damnnn Im, not this advanced yet lol but thanks yeah I just noticed I only wrote single strings in my lists, that was an accident.

Comment: @Ronel this is not really advanced python ;)

Comment: I updated the answer for the case of a list